# Regroup mySQL query results in a single CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I don't know if a solution to my problem exists.

I'm trying to regroup results from two similar queries, without using anything else than mySQL.

Here are my requests :

```
SELECT id, type as objet, decret as type, resume as synthese FROM projets
SELECT id, type as objet, decret as type, resume as synthese FROM articles
```

Obviously, I get an ambiguous error if I try

```
SELECT id, type as objet, decret as type, resume as synthese FROM articles, projets
```

I'd like to merge theses results in order to export it in a single CSV file, without using Excel manipulation or so.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try union

```
SELECT id, type as objet, decret as type, resume as synthese FROM projets
UNION
SELECT id, type as objet, decret as type, resume as synthese FROM articles
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Assuming the columns are the same in both tables.